# Ferrite Topology For Motor PWM

Tags: motor, pwm, dc-motor, emc, ferrite-bead

Brushed motors are pretty noisy devices, especially when driven with PWM. There are a number of techniques to reduce the transmitted noise (twisting wires, shielding etc) - one of these is using a ferrite bead.

I'm trying to figure out which exact topology is the best solution for reducing A) Electrical noise referred to the power line and B) EM noise transmitted to the outside world.

I assume that the optimal form would be one of the following (ferrite beads represented by inductors):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEOJJh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My questions are:

- Which of these is best?
- Should both of those capacitors be populated? Just one? Or none?
- What value should the capacitors be?
- It would be ideal to have another capacitor at the motor end of the cables, but this is tricky from a manufacturing perspective

Comment: It would be more ideal to replace the ferrite beads by inductors and make a proper 2nd order low-pass filter using (say) 10 uH and several hundred nF for C3.